# How can I remsh into a node and capture its I/O as if started with iex?

Tags: elixir

If I start my app with `iex`, I'll see my app's log statements at the console.

If I start my app detached and then `remsh` into it, how can I see that same output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, anything you execute from the remote shell will have it's group leader set to the shell's group leader, so I/O will work as expected.

For processes which were started from the main node, their group leader is already set, so their I/O won't be redirected to the remote shell. You can set the group leader of a process with `Process.group_leader/2`, for example: `Process.group_leader(pid, Process.group_leader())` which will set the group leader of `pid` to the group leader of the current process. You can configure the `:console` backend for Logger to also redirect to your shell with `Logger.configure_backend(:console, [device: Process.group_leader()])`. After that, all console Logger output should be directed to your remote shell.

**Be very careful about doing this.** If you do this on an application which will produce a lot of output, you run the risk of overloading the group leader, which may crash it, and thus anything attempting to write to it - and the likelihood of doing so increases when you are assigning a group leader on a remote node. I would suggest only ever doing this when experimenting or perhaps during development. In production, you should probably be writing logs to files anyway, and it is much safer to passively tail those logs via ssh than to change the group leader of the logger to your remote shell - particularly if you kill your shell without changing the group leader back; this will cause any process attempting to write to the group leader to crash. You'd also need to be careful that you store the group leader of the process before changing it so that you can ensure you change it back to the correct one.

Comment: Ah, some great notes there at the end I hadn't thought of.

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for here turned out to be the `attach` release task from @bitwalker's distillery package for release management.

https://github.com/bitwalker/distillery/blob/6700edb017804e51aec14dedb8df888d1db4e63c/priv/libexec/commands/help.sh